# Вывод полученной от пользователя переменной(python)

Tags: python

Приветствую. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести полученную от пользователя переменную через *print*. Например, получить имя пользователя в переменную, и создать приветствие с выводом значения уже полученной переменной

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Hello " + input("Print Youre Name")) # Hello Dima
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `input` к Вашим услугам:

```
# В аргументе указывается текст,
# который покажется пользователю.
x = input("Write a number: ")
x = int(x) * 2 - 5
print(x)
```